# htaccess - Redirecting duplicate urls to one page without having to do multiple times

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I have a duplicate urs like www.domain.com/en/article and www.domain.com/article ... they are both going to same page.

Now we are re-building the site and we would like to redirect duplicate urls like the above to one page without having to do it multiple times, like is there a regex or something of such.

This is the standard one I know: `#Redirect 301 /login http://www.domain.com/index.php?option=login`

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (^|/)article/?$ /new_article [R=301,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/new_(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(en)?/?(.*)$ /new_$2 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

It will redirect:

1. `www.domain.com/en/article` **or** `www.domain.com/article` to **`www.domain.com/new_article`**
2. `www.domain.com/en/another_article` **or** `www.domain.com/another_article` to **`www.domain.com/new_another_article`**
3. `www.domain.com/en/another_article2` **or** `www.domain.com/another_article2` to **`www.domain.com/new_another_article2`**

and so on..

Comment: Thanks but I am not sure how I have to implement it from www.domain.com/en/article and www.domain.com/article both to www.domain.com/new_article . Thanks.

Comment: oops, what is *new_article* here? please explain by giving some example links

Comment: I mean specific relation between `article` and `new_article`.
Will it precede with `new_` for all articles?

Comment: new_article is the new url I would like to redirect the old urls too. I want to redirect www.domain.com/en/article and www.domain.com/article without having to do it twice.

Comment: @Shina, see updated answer. I think thats what you need.

Answer (score 0):

How to correctly implement -problem duplicate pages .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^eintro.pl(.*) [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.eintro.pl/$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^index.html$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```